# Can't connect remix IDE using remixd

Tags: remix

I am following remix connection manual.
Running remixd like this:

> remixd -s ~/myProjects/cleanKyber/smart-contracts/contractsV5/
>   --remix-ide https://remix.ethereum.org/

trying to connect and getting this message on terminal:

> Connection from origin https://remix.ethereum.org rejected.

Following related questions, I made sure

> https

in both places is used.

Answer (score 2):

Found it, stupid mistake, but I missed it, so for anyone interested.

It was the extra '/' in my URL.

so had to use:

> remixd -s ~/myProjects/cleanKyber/smart-contracts/contractsV5/ 
>   --remix-ide https://remix.ethereum.org

and not:

> remixd -s ~/myProjects/cleanKyber/smart-contracts/contractsV5/ 
>   --remix-ide https://remix.ethereum.org/

Answer (score 0):

I also had this error trying to run it on windows PowerShell and connect from Chrome.

Odd thing is it worked fine in Brave. I was able to connect from Brave to remixd running from PowerShell just fine. However, to get it to connect from chrome on windows, I have to switch from from PowerShell to the old command prompt, and then it works a charm again.

Answer (score 0):

I was figuring out something and reached here. You do not need to give the --remix-ide part at all if you are just running one instance.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/75452)